# Didn't find class "LinearLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I installed and configured (correctly) a react-native-splash-screen in react native in a clean, freshly built application, and everything works, but when I add a TextInput tag to my application, it gives me an error

```
Didn't find class "LinearLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~CF3BRL0-1ytRKOrWde34AA==/com.tutorial-KHAA3IWAwibZh...
```

and this error is not in the console, it appears on the device itself.

I tried experimenting with other tags, such as Button, Image, etc., the problem did not go away.
I also tried to run the application on another device, it also did not work.